# formula to sort months - using helper column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to use a helper column to sort a table based on some criteria (min temp / max temp and allowed max temp columns)  , however I can't get it to work, it doesn't have to use a helper column but this how I tried to do it.

What I am trying to get is the expected result in red

My l2 (drag down) is

```
=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$11,"<="&$B2)
```

My J2 (drag down) is

=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,MATCH(ROWS($I$2:I2),$I$2:$I$8,0))

Tried to do

```
=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$11,"<="&$B2,B$2:B$11,"<="&$G$3)
```

I want to take into account the values in g3,g4,g5, 
The first items (months) in the ordered list (expected results)  are items that are smaller or equal that g3 in ascending order (lower to bigger).
The second items on the list are items that are > than g3 but smaller than g4 and there is a limit of items that is specified in G5

[image]

Comment: can you be bit more clear with J12:J18 data? how did you come up with that for each month?

Comment: How Feb (7) is coming after Jan (8)?

Comment: @GowthamShiva well spotted should be Feb 7 ,Jan8

Comment: Updated the picture and description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In order to handle duplicated values, 
the helper column is used to make unique keys,
which includes the month number, and sort them using `SMALL()` function. 
Assuming that month names in `A2:A11`  are text (not a date value, formatted as "MMM")
an array formula in `J2` and drag down to `J11` is

```
=SMALL(MONTH(DATEVALUE("1"&$A$2:$A$11&" 2001"))+ROUND(($B$2:$B$11+300)*1000,-2),ROW(I2)-ROW($I$1))
```

Assumes that the temperature values are rounded to only one digit after decimal point,
the value is adjusted (`+300`) to handle negative temperatures,
shifted to the left (`*1000`) and added the month number.

`D2`:

```
=IF(E2<=$H$3,TEXT(DATE(2001,MOD($J2,100),1),"MMM")," ")
```

`E2`:

```
=IF(ROUND($J2/1000-300,1)<=$H$3,ROUND($J2/1000,1)-300," ")
```

`D3` and drag down to `D11`:

```
=IF(OR(E3<=$H$3,AND(E3>$H$3,E3<$H$4,COUNTIF(E$2:E2,">"&$H$3)<$H$5)),TEXT(DATE(2001,MOD($J3,100),1),"MMM")," ")
```

`E3` and drag down to `E11`:

```
=IF(OR(ROUND($J3/1000-300,1)<=$H$3,AND(ROUND($J3/1000-300,1)>$H$3,ROUND($J3/1000-300,1)<$H$4,COUNTIF(E$2:E2,">"&$H$3)<$H$5)),ROUND($J3/1000-300,1)," ")
```

Optional conditional formatting in `D2:D11`:

[image]

Optional conditional in `E2:E11`:

[image]

Comment: that works perfectly, just one question .how would you change the formula in order for the sorting to become generic (if you name the name of the months to anything else to still work ). thanks

Comment: @Athanatos: thanks for your persistence. 
Well, generic sorting will considerably change the original question.
The approach used in this answer benefits from the specific of the data,
and need some significant changes.
General sorting is an interesting question of itself
and can demand to handle a broad range of nuances.

Answer (score 1):

Please check these formulas. It should work for you,

[image]

Formula in `column J`,

`=IF(SMALL($B$2:$B$10,ROW(1:1))<=$G$3,SMALL($B$2:$B$10,ROW(1:1)),IF(AND(SMALL($B$2:$B$10,ROW(1:1))<=$G$4,COUNTIF($J$2:$J2,">" & $G$3)<$G$5),SMALL($B$2:$B$10,ROW(1:1)),""))`

Formula in `column I`,

`=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(J3,B:B,0),1)`

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need any info.

Comment: There is one problem: if there are non-unique temperature readings
(e.g. `Apr=11` and `Sep=11` in the example),
their corresponding month appears the same (`Apr`).